# Python try except function with time-out limit

Tags: selenium

I am searching within a PowerBI dashboard with Selenium a certain pop-up window to insert a search term. I can only do this in stable way by creating a function which looks for all input fields and then try to send the term within a try-except-clause which takes very long.

Hence I am wondering if it is possible to insert a command how long to wait till an exception occurs.

Here is my code

```
fields_searchheader = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".searchHeader.show > .searchInput")
for i in fields_searchheader:
    try:
        i.clear()
        i.send_keys("hallo)
        # wait function till exception if no feedback
    except Exception:
        print("d")
```

Would be great to get an idea. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: 2) What exception is thrown in case it will be thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

it will wait *up to*..not for the number of seconds..

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys









def InputByCSS(NameOfObject, WhatToSend):
    try:
        item = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, NameOfObject)))
        item.click()
        item.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
        item.send_keys(WhatToSend)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("InputByXPATH Error: Couldn't input by XPATH on: " + str(NameOfObject))
        pass

fields_searchheader = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".searchHeader.show > .searchInput")
for i in fields_searchheader:
    try:
        InputByCSS(i,'hallo')
    except Exception:
        print("d")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to you to use - [Expected Conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

And also to make it stable - tune it by using [polling](https://polling2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#polling-for-selenium-webdriver-elements).